# Change my url from domani/index.html to domani/index

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to change my url from domani.com/index.html to domain.com/index , i tried many options, but none worked. i am using aruba as server, i don't know is important and windows hosting

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it should work

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried, but always the same error 1° "HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found" when i refresh this "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found"